# Get moving average over time frame in PostgreSQL with inconsistent data

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, moving-average

I have a table called `answers` with columns `created_at` and `response`, response being an integer `0` (for 'no'), `1` (for 'yes'), or `2` (for 'don't know').  I want to get a moving average for the response values, filtering out 2s for each day, only taking in to account the previous 30 days.  I know you can do `ROWS BETWEEN 29 AND PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` but that only works if you have data for each day, and in my case there might be no data for a week or more.

My current query is this:

```
SELECT answers.created_at, answers.response,
    AVG(answers.response)
      OVER(ORDER BY answers.created_at::date ROWS 
        BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS rolling_average
  FROM answers
  WHERE answers.user_id = 'insert_user_id'' 
    AND (answers.response = 0 OR answers.response = 1)
  GROUP BY answers.created_at, answers.response
  ORDER BY answers.created_at::date
```

But this will return an average based on the previous rows, if a user responded with a `1` on `2018-3-30` and a `0` on `2018-5-15`, the rolling average on `2018-5-15` would be `0.5` instead of `0` as I want. How can I create a query that will only take in to account the responses that were created within the last 30 days for the rolling average?

Comment: Provide example data on sqlfiddle.com and add expected results based on the example data..

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: " I know you can do ROWS BETWEEN 29 AND PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW but that only works if you have data for each day, and in my case there might be no data for a week or more."  PostgreSQL 8.0+ supports  `generate_series()` functions to generate a calendar table for that.

Answer (score 4):

Since Postgres 11 you can do this:

```
SELECT created_at, 
       response,
       AVG(response) OVER (ORDER BY created_at 
                           RANGE BETWEEN '29 day' PRECEDING AND current row) AS rolling_average 
FROM answers
WHERE user_id = 1
  AND response in (0,1)
ORDER BY created_at;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        d.created_at, d.response, 
        Avg(d.response) OVER(ORDER BY d.created_at::date rows BETWEEN 29 PRECEDING AND CURRENT row) AS rolling_average 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT 
            COALESCE(a.created_at, d.dates) AS created_at, response, a.user_id 
        FROM 
            (SELECT generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2018-05-31'::date, '1day'::interval)::date AS dates) d 
        LEFT JOIN 
            (SELECT * FROM answers WHERE answers.user_id = 'insert_user_id' AND ( answers.response = 0 OR answers.response = 1)) a 
        ON d.dates = a.created_at::date 
    ) d 
    GROUP BY d.created_at, d.response 
) agg WHERE agg.response IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY agg.created_at::date`

- generate_series creates list of days - you have to set reasonable boundaries
- this list of days is LEFT JOINed with preselected answers
- this result is used for rolling average calculation
- after it I select only records with response and I get:

`created_at | response | rolling_averagte 
2018-03-30 | 1        | 1.00000000000000000000 
2018-05-15 | 0        | 0.00000000000000000000`